# Bash alias to pipe an arbitrary command to less

Tags: bash, shell, perforce

In a nutshell I'm trying to make Perforce work with less. At the moment a command such as `p4 diff` will happily dump 5000 lines to the console. I want commands like this to automatically pipe into less without me having to type it (you know, like g*t does).

My two best "solutions" so far:

"Solution" 1 - A bash function

```
function p4() {
    pager=""
    if [ "$1" = "diff" ]
    then
        pager=" | less"
    fi

    /bin/sh -c "/usr/local/bin/p4 "$@" $pager"
}
```

Problem with this is Perforce syntax overlaps Unix shell syntax. 
i.e. `p4 jobs ...@\>2015/01/20` will fail horribly because of the `>` symbol.

"Solution" 2 - Function with a different name

```
function p4d() {
    p4 diff "$@" | less
}
```

Which is lame because now I have to remember to type `p4d` instead of `p4 diff` and won't work for `p4 diff2` for the same reason as solution 1.

Are there any shell or Perforce tricks I can use to get commands like `p4 diff` to pipe into `less` without me having to remember to type it all the time?

Is there a way I can safely wrap the `p4` arguments (`$@`) so that shell symbols like `>` are not reinterpreted but `|` is?

Does not have to be bash. If you have some funky shell from the 60s which solves my problem let's hear it!

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How do you *normally* get around that insane syntax, and why wouldn't you do the same thing when invoking the function?

Comment: Because there are multiple levels of subshells involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eval-type solutions generally fail to be robust against arguments with odd characters in them. On the other hand, they are often unnecessary.

Instead of

```
/bin/sh -c "/usr/local/bin/p4 "$@" $pager"
```

which has a quotation error (the quotes around `$@` are actually unquoting `$@` although fixing that won't help since you would actually need to insert escapes into the string passed to `bash -c`), you can just execute the command directly:

```
/usr/local/bin/p4 "$@" | "$pager"
```

That requires that `$pager` be defined; you would probably want:

```
if [[ $pager ]]; then
  /usr/local/bin/p4 "$@" | "$pager"
else
  /usr/local/bin/p4 "$@"
fi
```

The explicit path is a bit annoying. With bash, you can make this more robust by using the `command` builtin:

```
if [[ $pager ]]; then
  command p4 "$@" | "$pager"
else
  command p4 "$@"
fi
```

That introduces a small duplication of code, and it's a bit much if you're going to use that snipped in various places. You could define the following function (in your `~/.bashrc` file, for example):

```
page() {
  if [[ $pager ]]; then
    "$@" | "${pager[@]}"
  else
    "$@"
  fi
}
```

Then your `p4` script could be:

```
p4() {
  local pager=
  if [[ $1 = diff ]]; then pager=less; fi
  page command p4 "$@"
}
```

There are lots of other variants. Note the use of `"${pager[@]}"` in the `page` function; this allows `pager` to be an array, in case you want to pass arguments to less. For example:

```
( pager=(less -N); p4 diff ...; )
```

(The parentheses are to make the setting of `pager` local; you can't use the normal `var=value command` syntax with arrays.)

Comment: I see, `command` seems to be the secret sauce I was missing. 
Unfortunately this means I cannot hide the pipe character inside the `$pager` variable anymore so we introduce a parallel maintenance issue by having almost identical code in two different places. I guess I can live with that.

Comment: @user4495048  Alternately, if `$pager` isn't set, you could set it to a default pager. On another subject, consider testing whether stdout is a TTY (`if [[ -t 1 ]]...`). If p4 output is already being piped to a file or another program, the user probably doesn't want to insert `less` into the pipeline.

Comment: @user4495048: Edited with another suggestion.

Comment: Could you elaborate about what the purpose of `command` is?  Since `command` works only with built-ins and executables already in `PATH`, why not just invoke `p4` directly with no absolute path?

Comment: @jamesdlin
`> why not just invoke p4 directly with no absolute path`

If this code was in a wrapper script also called `p4` then it might call itself. From what I understand there are also general security concerns with omitting the absolute path in script; for example someone could mess with your PATH variable and the script will suddenly do something different when it calls just `p4`.

Comment: @user4495048 Oh right, it's to avoid the recursion.  I don't think the security concern matters; `command p4` depends on `PATH` too (besides, if someone could mess with *your* `PATH`, they could mess with plenty of other things).

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion for how to implement your `p4` function:

```
function p4() {
    if [[ $1 == diff ]]; then
        command p4 "$@" | less
    else
        command p4 "$@"
    fi
}
```

This will eliminate the quoting and escaping problems you're seeing.

You could eliminate the repeated `command p4 "$@"` pieces if piping to `cat` is okay (some commands will behave differently when stdout is connected to a TTY vs. a pipe; I don't know if perforce cares):

```
function p4() {
    command p4 "$@" | if [[ $1 == diff ]]; then less; else cat; fi
}
```